# Ruby hash with dates as keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

When I do this request on my database :

```
users_count = User.select("date_trunc('day', created_at)").group("date_trunc('day', created_at)").count
```

I then have a hash with dates as keys :

```
# => {2016-07-29 00:00:00 UTC=>1, 2016-07-06 00:00:00 UTC=>1, 2016-07-07 00:00:00 UTC=>1, 2016-07-13 00:00:00 UTC=>2, 2016-07-04 00:00:00 UTC=>421, 2016-07-09 00:00:00 UTC=>3, 2016-07-08 00:00:00 UTC=>2, 2016-07-22 00:00:00 UTC=>1, 2016-07-19 00:00:00 UTC=>1, 2016-07-21 00:00:00 UTC=>2}
```

But then I'm not able to retrieve data by date :

```
date = DateTime.new(2016, 7, 29)
# => Fri, 29 Jul 2016
users_count[date]
# => nil
users_count.keys.first === date
# => true
users_count[users_count.keys.first]
# => 1
```

How can I retrieve the number of users created on specific days in a single request? And why is ruby giving me a value of nil for a key that is present in the hash?

Thanks for your help.

ruby version 2.2.4, Rails version 4.2.5.1

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you 100% sure they are `Date`s? After all, the `inspect` output you showed for the `Hash` keys (`'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS TZ'`) doesn't match the `inspect` output you showed for your `Date` (`'Www, DD Mmm, YYYY'`) which clearly indicates that the `Hash` keys are *not* `Date`s. Since they incorporate both a `Date` and a `Time`, they are probably `DateTime`s, not `Date`s.

Comment: sorry for not making my question clearer, I added it.
@Jörg W Mittag : I am 100% sure of the ruby output I gave you. DateTime doesn't solve it for me.

Comment: Okay, then maybe it's a `Time`, or something else entirely. It's unfortunately impossible to tell with the limited amount of information in your question. Pretty much the only thing we *can* tell from your question is that it's *not* a `Date`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime` instance instead, converted to time, since hash keys are apparently instances of `Time`:

```
date = DateTime.new(2016,7,29,0,0,0).to_time
```

Comment: I had tried this too, but it doesn't work. And I tried it again, to be sure.

Comment: What does (assuming your hash dates⇒values is stored in `hash` variable)  `puts hash.first.first.class.inspect` output?

Comment: `users_count.first.first.class.inspectirst.class.inspect` outputs `# => "Time"`

Comment: That's the correct answer, thank you very much :) Can you explain to me why the hash keys include my key, but then it is not recognised as a key? Why is class checked for equality when retrieving value in hash, but not when using `===`?

Comment: It is not because the class equality is checked, it is because an instance of `DateTime` time is by no means the same as the instance of `Time`, but it can be converted to it. One might think about this as about `"42" != 42, but "42" == 42.to_s`.

Comment: Hash key comparison in ruby is done with the `.eql?` method. `===` method is for case statements comparison.